# Cannot find R package vctrs under in Rstudio mirror https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/

Tags: r, tidyverse

I cannot find anymore the R package `vctrs` in the mirror https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/. This package is a dependent on the `tidyverse`.

I am working on a Citrix corporate machine, so I cannot (easily) install Rtools to load it manually.
I tried to go on https://cloud.r-project.org/ to raise this issue, but I could not find a way to raise this...maybe the community here knows better!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been added now on 02SEP20.